# Conditional calculation dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The calculation I would like to do on this dataframe is quit simple still I do not manage to think of any preliminary code. The data in columns '10' are sorted (ascending order).

I want to:
1. first row in column '10' * 1.05 (add 5%)
      ex: 871103 * 1.05 = 914658.15 (the closest value in the df is 914657)
2. count the number of rows to find the data closer to the result find 
   in 1.
      ex: 16th rows in the df below.
3. sum up the same number of rows in column '2'.
     ex: 0.04242 in the df below

DATAFRAME SAMPLE:

```
             2              10
1                             
asks:   0.1546         871103
        0.011          871280
        0.004          871315
        0.01           871333
        0.004          871341
        0.0106         871347
        0.01           871347
        0.023          871363
        0.002          871365
        0.01           871401
        0.001          871462
        0.139          871477
        0.005          871483
        0.005          871499
        0.03           871502
        0.005          914657
        0.01119222     914800
        0.50000013     920000
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
             2               10
 1                             
   asks:    0.4242         914657
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `df` is your dataframe:

```
idx = (df['10'] - (df['10'][0] * 1.05)).abs().idxmin()
csdf = df.cumsum()
csdf['10'] = df['10']
```

`idx` is the index of the row you are looking for: obtained looking fo the minimum of the absolute value of the difference between each value of column `'10'` and the first value of column `'10'` multiplied by 1.05.
`csdf` is a new dataframe obtained doing the cumulative sum of the elements of `df`, and then I replaced column `'10'` of `csdf` with the original column `'10'` of `df`.

So

```
csdf.iloc[idx]
```

is the row you are looking for.